# I2C bit bang as a slave device?

Tags: bit-manipulation, linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi3, i2c, beagleboneblack

My goal is to have my beaglebone black(bbb) act as an i2c slave device for `raspberry pi`. However, the Linux driver is an i2c master only.

So I am no currently wondering if it would be possible to write my own custom i2c bit-bang device driver for my BBB acting as the slave and using the `gpios` for sda and scl lines.

Is it possible that I can write such a driver so that when I scan the i2c bus on my raspberry pi, I will find my BBB with a provided slave address?

I heard about programming the Pru pins on the BBB but I believe that I need to go bare metal to accomplish this and remove my operating system so I would like to avoid this option.

Comment: You will have a whole set of nice timing problems unless you are not running in a *hard real time* mode. Btw, almost any Intel (Atom-based) board has I²C controllers from Synopsys which has slave support. Of course you may find other (non-Intel) board with the same controller.

Comment: @0andriy So i guess to accomplish the hard real time problem would be to to go bare metal and use the pru pins on the bbb? I was a bit hesitant with programming bare metal cause i am not to familiar with the interface/ide used to program it. However if its the only way without having to buy a new board ill look into it. The only functionality i need is pwm output/input and i2c bit-bang

Comment: The Pru Pins (with a PRU program setting them) is as bare metal as you can get, so I do not understand the "but". Here is a project, where a I2C master driver was created: https://github.com/chanakya-vc/PRU-I2C_SPI_master Perhaps you could take this as base for your slave code?

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks for the link, i think it will be helpful. I was doing some more research on the pru pins and how to program them. I learned that i don't need to remove my OS to use these fast bare metal pins. Thanks